# How to format timeago to return minutes

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/timeago) to render a timestamp in my flutter app. The timestamp is of type `Timestamp` in firestore. This is what I currently have:

//Helper method

```
static String ago(Timestamp timestamp) {
    if (timestamp == null) return 'Unknown';
    return timeago.format(timestamp.toDate()).toString();
  }
```

and to display:

```
Text(Helpers.ago(order.timestamp))
```

It works fine, but it returns "timeago" in hours..how can I format to return minutes?

Answer (score 0):

You could save it to a local variable then use

```
int.tryParse(value)
double.tryParse(value)
```

To get it in integer form. This can be mathematically converted to minutes. this is the long way